# How to get the refrence of a textview inside a cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a card(cardview) in which i have created a textview named edit. i want that if i click on the edit textview in any card it should do want i want and get the position of the card whose edit is clicked. I have tried different ways for this. i was able to click the edit text but should i get the position of the card whose edit is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //GETTING THE EACH OBJECT OF EXPENSEDATA [CONTAINING EACH ROW FROM DB] FROM ARRAYLIST
    ExpenseData ed = expenseDataArrayList.get(position);

    //GETTING VALUE OF CARDVIEW FROM ABOVE CONSTRUCTOR AND SETTING IT TO cardView
    CardView cardView = holder.cardView;

  /*GETTING REFRENCESS OF EACH VIEW
    AND EXTRACTING THE DATA FROM EXPENSEDATA OBJECT USING GETTER METHODS
    AND SETTING VALUES TO RESPECTIVE VIEWS
    ONE BY ONE*/
    TextView dayTv = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.day);
    dayTv.setText(ed.getDay());
    TextView dateTv = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    dateTv.setText(ed.getDate());
    TextView expNameTv = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.exp_name);
    expNameTv.setText(ed.getExpName());
    TextView expTypeTv = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.exp_type);
    expTypeTv.setText(ed.getExpType());
    TextView expAmtTv = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.exp_amt);
    expAmtTv.setText(Double.toString(ed.getExpAmt()));

    TextView edit = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           onClickEdit();
        }
    });
}

public void onClickEdit() {

    AddExpenseDialog addExpenseDialog = new AddExpenseDialog();
    addExpenseDialog.show(((Activity)context).getFragmentManager(), "update ima");

//i want to get the position of the card whose textview is clicked.

}
```

Comment: Use onClickEdit(position);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want that if i click on the edit textview in any card it should do
>   want i want and get the position of the card whose edit is clicked.

To get the position you can use the adapter `getAdapterPosition()` method which returns the position of your item in the data source of that adapter, which is `expenseDataArrayList` in your example